# 1 to many > 1 to many grouping/sub queries

Tags: mysql

I have a shopping cart and need to list the orders in a tabular format. Each order can have several products in it, and each product may have several options (these are book type products, you can choose different cover colours (at no extra charge), or have your name embossed on it (at an extra charge)

[image: ERD]

What I have so far is

```
    select 
order_id,
sum(price_paid * ordered_qty),
group_concat(product_code SEPARATOR ' / ') 
from
orders join  order_lines USING (order_id)
where
DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y%m') >= '201203' and DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y%m') <= '201203' and order_status = 'SHIPPED' and item_status = 'LINESHIPPED'
group by order_id 
order by order_id
```

This ignores the options (order_line_options table) and returns this:

```
58  21.98   SKU-12 / SKU-12
59  10.99   SKU-12
60  67.78   SKU-31 / SKU-12 / SKU-56
61  259.45  SKU-98 / SKU-06 / SKU-98
62  9.49    SKU-40 / SKU-36
```

Which correctly sums the unit cost *  QTY and lists the product codes in a single row (duplicate product codes indicate different options ordered)

What I need now is the options included to products results in something like:

```
58  21.98   SKU-12 (Color: Red, 0.00 - Printname 0.00) / SKU-12  (Color: Blue, 0.00 - Printname 4.95)
```

Just the first order shown with SKU-12 ordered twice, once in red and once in blue with the name printed for $4.95

I've spend the day trying extra group by / group_concat and sub queries but I'm not even getting close to a solution so any help would be great.
Kevin

Comment: Does each line_item_option have all three fields filled out?  (More specifically, what field does "Printname" come from?)

Comment: line_item_option could have any number from 0 to any (but typically 1 or 2) records/options associated with a specific product. And sone will have a cost of zero, and thus can be ignored and other with > 0 cost need to be summed. "printname" is just an example option name (ie the cust took the option where they have their name embossed on the cover at a charge of $4.95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use two correlated subqueries in the SELECT clause.  I imagine the following should work for you:

```
select 
order_id,
sum( price_paid 
     * ordered_qty 
     -- add the cost of any subitems for this line
     + IFNULL((select sum(option_cost) 
          from order_line_options olo
         where olo.order_line_id = order_lines.order_line_id),0)
),
--Here product_code
group_concat(
  CONCAT(product_code, 
  ' (', 
  (select group_concat(
          CONCAT(option_name, ': ',
                 option_value, ', '
                 option_cost
                 )
          SEPARATOR '-'
          )
     from order_line_options olo
    where olo.order_line_id = order_lines.order_line_id
    group by olo.order_line_id
   ),
   ')'
  ) -- end of CONCAT() which creates subitem list
  SEPARATOR ' / '
) 
from
orders join  order_lines USING (order_id)
where
  DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y%m') >= '201203' and DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y%m') <=   '201203' and order_status = 'SHIPPED' and item_status = 'LINESHIPPED'
group by order_id 
order by order_id
```

Comment: Thanks greenlion, will try that when back in the office

Comment: You might have to wrap the group_concat in the subquery with an IFNULL.  I don't remember how CONCAT treats NULL values in MySQL.  Oracle treats them as empty string.

Comment: Many thanks greenline for all your effort - it seems to work perfectly. I just changed IFNULL((select sum(option_cost) to IFNULL((select sum(option_cost * ordered_qty) and yes I did need the IFNULL as "CONCAT() returns NULL if any argument is NULL" from the docs. Thanks again, Kevin

Comment: Your where clause could use a little work too.  As written, you will scan a lot of records (at least _all_ SHIPPED orders, assuming there is an index on order_status) because you use a function on the order_date column.  Instead use order_date >= '2012-03-01' and order_date < '2012-03-01' + interval 1 month.  This will use an index on (order_status, order_date) or (order_date).

Comment: Thanks again:) That clause will work on a datetime? I mean I know it will, but I thought I was doing it the more efficient way. I'll try that then. Yes status is an index - i just cropped the ERD image as it's pretty long