# 3 Table Join with SUM and GROUP BY not working

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

I have three tables that I'm working with.

1. AccountingLine - Holds the generic account details
2. Budget - Holds the budget data for each AccountingLine  (Many rows per AccountingLine)
3. Actual - Holds the actual cost data for each AccountingLine (Many rows per AccountingLine)

I'm trying to get the results in a single query which will return ALL ROWS from the AccountingLine table, and SUM the Amounts for each AccountingLine from the Budget and Actuals table.

Using the SQL below, the SUM isn't working for the Budget or Actual data. If I remove one of the joins and one of the SUM functions then it calculates correctly for the single joined table.  Very strange... anyone run across this with multiple SUM functions on three or more tables in MySQL?

```
SELECT  A.*, SUM(B.`amount`) AS BudgetAmount, SUM(ACT.`amount`) as ActualAmount 
FROM accounting_line A 
LEFT JOIN budget B ON B.accounting_line_id = A.accounting_line_id
LEFT JOIN actual ACT ON  ACT.accounting_line_id = A.accounting_line_id
GROUP BY A.`accounting_line_id`
```

By issuing the statement above, I'd expect to see the accounting_line fields, the SUM of the Budget amounts for each accounting_line and the SUM of the Actual amounts for each accounting_line.

I've searched all over and can't find an instance of multiple SUM functions. Thanks so much for any advice.

Josh

Table Data is below:

```
    Table: AccountingLine

      act_line_id   department
    ----------------------------------  
                1   Sales   
                2   HumanResources


Table: Budget


        budget_id   actg_line_id     amount
    ----------------------------------------------  
                1              1          3500.00
                2              2          5000.00
                3              2          15000.00

Table: Actual


        actual_id   actg_line_id     amount
    ----------------------------------------------  
                1              1        1000.00
                2              2         500.00
                3              2        9000.00
```

Comment: I have answered this question before here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746613/1-to-many-1-to-many-grouping-sub-queries/11746868#11746868

Comment: Justin, I saw that answer but I couldn't figure out how to adapt it to my particular situation.

Comment: @Josh check my answer below, maybe it could help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `join` repeats each matching row in the other table.  So if you have 3 rows in three tables and join them together, you end up with 9 rows.  If you sum, each sum from the second and third table is 3x too high.

One solution is to sum in a subquery, so that the `join` only finds one row:

```
SELECT   A.*
,        B.SumAmount as BudgetAmount
,        ACT.SumAmount as ActualAmount 
FROM     accounting_line A 
LEFT JOIN 
        (
        select  accounting_line_id
        ,       sum(amount) as SumAmount
        from    budget
        group by
                accounting_line_id
        ) as B
ON      B.accounting_line_id = A.accounting_line_id
LEFT JOIN 
        (
        select  accounting_line_id
        ,       sum(amount) as SumAmount
        from    actual
        group by
                accounting_line_id
        ) as ACT 
ON      ACT.accounting_line_id = A.accounting_line_id
```

Comment: Andormar, this works like a champ! One more follow-up... I'd like to add a column that calculates the difference between Budgeted and Actual and have that show as a new column.  When I try and add in a simple SUM(BudgetAmount - ActualAmount) into the SELECT statement it doesn't like it.  Any ideas?

Comment: The outer query isn't grouping, so omit the `sum`, like `BudgetAmount - ActualAmount as Difference`

Comment: Perfect.  Excatly what I was looking for Andomar!  Thanks so much for the quick replies everyone.

Answer (score 2):

try this modified one, calculate it's totals on a `subquery`

```
SELECT  a.*, b.totalBudget, c.totalActual
FROM AccountingLine a LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT actg_line_id, SUM(amount) totalBudget
        FROM Budget
        GROUP BY actg_line_id
        ) b on a.act_line_id = b.actg_line_id
    LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT actg_line_id, SUM(amount) totalActual
        FROM Actual
        GROUP BY actg_line_id
        ) c on a.act_line_id = c.actg_line_id
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ae3a/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select A.* ,SUM(B.Amount) As BudgetAmount,SUM(Act.Amount) As ActualAmount 
from AccountingLine  A
INNER JOIN Budget B 
ON B.budget_id = A.actg_line_id 
INNER JOIN Actual Act 
ON Act.actual_id = A.accounting_line_id  
Grounp By A.accounting_line_id
```

Comment: The double join will cause each row in B to be repeated for each row in ACT.  So this will double-count rows from B and ACT.