# Displaying data with respect to specific date?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, union

> I am trying to make a reporting system where I need to display report
>   for each date.

[image]

> These is my table schema for selected_items [image] 
>   This is stock_list[image]
>
> I am using php in the back-end and java in the front end to display
>   the data. I tried a couple of queries to get the desired output but so
>   far I am not able to get it.These are some of the queries i used.

```
SELECT
   COALESCE(stock_list.date, selected_items.date) AS date,
   SUM( stock_list.qty ) AS StockSum,
   SUM( stock_list.weight ) AS Stockweight,
   COUNT( selected_items.barcode ) AS BilledItems,
   SUM( selected_items.weight ) AS Billedweight
FROM stock_list join selected_items
ON stock_list.date = selected_items.date
GROUP BY COALESCE(stock_list.date, selected_items.date)
ORDER BY COALESCE(stock_list.date, selected_items.date);
```

> This gives me the first five columns but the output gives me wrong values.
>   Then I also tried Union.

```
SELECT SUM( qty ) AS StockSum, SUM( weight ) AS Stockweight
FROM  `stock_list` 
WHERE DATE LIKE  '08-Jan-2016'
UNION SELECT COUNT( barcode ) AS BilledItems, SUM( weight ) AS Billedweight
FROM  `selected_items` 
WHERE DATE LIKE  '08-Jan-2016'
UNION SELECT SUM( qty ) AS TotalStock, SUM( weight ) AS TotalWeight
FROM  `stock_list`;
```

> Here I get the correct values for four columns but the problem is the >result is displayed in two columns when I would like it to be in 4 columns.
>   Can anyone guide me please I have figured the java part of it but I am not good at php and mysql.
>   Thank you

Comment: Thank you @LordAnomander can you help with a solution

Comment: Will you share table schema?

Comment: Yes sure @AnkiiG please check the updated question.Thank you

Comment: @LordAnomander no problem I am new to programming so I like to experiment sometimes I learn something new Sometimes I don't

Comment: @AndroidNewBee did you try my query per chance? I'm just curious whether it works. :)

Comment: @LordAnomander it did work but did not give me the expected answer. But yes it showed me the way.Thank you so much :)

Comment: @AndroidNewBee ok, glad I could give you a suggestion you could build your solution on :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SQL Fiddle crashed while I was trying to execute this query

```
SELECT sl.date AS date, B.qtySum AS StockSum, B.weightSum AS Stockweight,
C.barcodeCount AS BilledItems, C.weightSum AS Billedweight
FROM stock_list sl 
JOIN (SELECT SUM(qty) as qtySum, SUM(weight) as weightSum
      FROM STOCK_LIST GROUP BY date) AS B
ON B.date = sl.date
JOIN (SELECT SUM (weight) AS weightSum, COUNT(barcode) AS barcodeCount
      FROM SELECTED_ITEMS GROUP BY date) AS C
ON C.date = sl.date;
```

[As it was tried here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337037/3-table-join-with-sum-and-group-by-not-working). The problem with joins is that the rows will be joined multiple times and thus, the sum goes awry. For example, you have four rows that are joined from the second table and so the sum is four times higher as it should. With subqueries you can avoid this problem as you count and sum up variables before joining them and therefore, the numbers should fit. Alas, I couldn't run the query so I'm not 100% sure it works, but it should be the right approach.